# Перевод строки в jquery

Tags: jquery

Дан код

```
var message = $("#message").val();
...
$("#commentBlock").append("<blockquote><footer>"+message+"</footer></blockquote>");
```

Нужно сделать чтобы переменная message выводилась с переводом строк и не отображала html символы.

в jquery не силён, в php это бы выглядело так - **nl2br(htmlspecialchars($message))**

Comment: В гугель-то не пробовали ходить? `javascript htmlspecialchars`

Comment: @u_mulder помогло `message = message.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#039;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');`
но с переносом строки так и не разобрался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message = message.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#039;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
```

Comment: Руками энкодить html...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#commentBlock").append($("<blockquote>").html($("<footer>").text(message).css("white-space", "pre-line")));
```